# white frame on html page about 50px wide don't know where it comes from

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

There's a column of about 50px wide on the right of the document that i have no idea where it comes from, I have tripled checked both my html and css and can't find where it is generated.

Here is my html:

```
                     <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html lang="es">
                <head>
                    <meta charset="utf-8">
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                    <meta name="description" content="?.?">
                    <meta name="author" content="?.?">
                    <meta property="og:title" content="Sitio Web de Balam Tech">
                    <meta property="og:image" content="assets/img/balamtech-logo.png">
                    <meta property="og:site_mame" content="Balam Tech">
                    <meta property="og:description" content="?.?">
                    <title>Balam Tech - Inicio</title>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/libs/css/bootstrap.min.css">
                    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/main.css">
                </head>
                <body>
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                        <div class="container">
                            <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand"><img class="topbar-thumbnail" src="assets/img/balamtech-logo.png" alt="Balam Tech Logo"> Balam Tech</a>
                                <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".mainNavbar">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></span>
                                </button>
                                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse mainNavbar">
                                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                        <li class="active-tab"><a href="#quien">¿Quiénes somos?</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#servicios">Servicios</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#contact">Contáctanos</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#login">Login</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#registrate">Regístrate</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-main-page" role="main">
                                <div class="container space-top-jumbotron-main-page text-center">
                                    <h1>Balam Tech</h1>
                                    <p>Productos y Servicios de Primera Calidad</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Contáctanos</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>    
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="container" id="quien">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <h2 class="text-center">¿Quiénes somos?</h2>
                                <div style="height: 40px;"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <img src="assets/img/balamtech-logo.png" alt="logo de Balam Tech" title="Balam Tech" class="img-logo-main-page">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                    <h3>Balam Tech</h3>
                                    <article class="text-main-page">
                                        <p><b>Balam Tech</b> es una empresa que pertene a Grupo San Martín.</p>
                                        <p><b>Balam Tech</b> se dedicada a prestar servicios de desarrollo de software web y
                                        a la venta de productos de software genérico. Más Información en la sección de servicios y productos.</p>
                                        <p>Puedes ponerte en contacto con nosotros al correo
                                        <b><a href="mailto:info@balamtech.com">info@balamtech.com</a></b></p>
                                    </article>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary pull-right">Leer Más</a>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="height: 70px;"></div>
                    <div class="second-tier">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <h2 class="text-center">Nuestros Servicios</h2>
                                    <div style="height: 40px;"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <h3 class="text-center">Software Web a la Medida</h3>
                                    <article class="text-main-page">
                                        <p>Nosotros desarrollamos <b>Software Web</b> con los estándares más altos, con
                                        tecnología de punta y con escalabilidad horizontal y vertical.</p>
                                        <p>El <b>Software Web</b> te ofrece la ventaja de ser compatible con muchos de los dispositivos
                                        que se utilizan hoy en día. ¿Smartphones, tabletas, ipads?, No te preocupes, te tenemos
                                        cubierto.</p>
                                    </article>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <h3 class="text-center">Desarrollo de Portales y Plataformas Web</h3>
                                    <article class="text-main-page">
                                        <p>Hoy en día los portales y plataformas empresariales y de negocios son un indicio del
                                        grado de calidad y profesionalidad que una empresa, compañia o institución posee.</p>
                                        <p>Nuestros desarrolladores y diseñadores se encargan de que tu empresa tenga una imágen
                                        estrictamente profesional y seria en la Web.</p>
                                    </article>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <h3 class="text-center">Diseño de Correos Electrónicos</h3>
                                    <article class="text-main-page">
                                        <p>Siempre hay una razón para mandar un correo a un cliente, a un contacto, a una empresa, etc.</p>
                                        <p>Se vuelve un problema poder visualizar de manera uniforme un correo al haber tantos dispositivos
                                        y resoluciones diferentes en el mercado.</p>
                                        <p>Nosotros te ofrecemos una solución que las grandes empresas internacionales utilizan: Diseño de Correo Electrónico Responsivo.</p>
                                    </article>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <h3 class="text-center">Desarrollo de Aplicaciones Móviles</h3>
                                    <article class="text-main-page">
                                        <p>Hoy en día, mas del 50% de la audiencia que visita un sitio o aplicación web
                                        lo hace desde un dispositivo móvil, es decir un smartphone o tableta.</p>
                                        <p>El diseño responsivo es una solución bastante útil, pero muchas veces, es
                                        el grado de complejidad de el sitio o aplicación requiere de mayor especialización,
                                        para el cual te ofrecemos otra solución: <b>Aplicaciones Móviles.</b></p>
                                    </article>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="height: 30px;"></div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <img src="assets/img/techs.png" class="img-tech-main">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div style="height: 50px;"></div>
                                <h2 class="text-center">Contáctanos</h2>
                                <hr>
                                <div style="height: 40px;"></div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <img src="assets/img/androidmessage.png" class="icon-message pull-left">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <form method="post" role="form" class="text-center">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label" for="uname">Nombre</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="uname" name="uname" placeholder="nombre">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label" for="uemail">Correo</label>
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" id="uemail" name="uemail" placeholder="correo electrónico">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label" for="uempresa">Empresa</label>
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" id="uempresa" name="uempresa" placeholder="empresa">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label" for="umensaje">Mensaje</label>
                                            <textarea class="form-control" id="umensaje" name="umensaje" placeholder="mensaje..."></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right">Enviar Mensaje</button>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <footer class="footer">

                        </footer>
                    <script src="assets/libs/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="assets/libs/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                </body>
                </html>
```

and here is my css:

```
            @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);
            body, html{
                font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important;
                height: 100% !important;
                width: 100% !important;
            }
            .jumbotron-main-page{
                background: url('../img/bg.jpg') 50% 50% fixed no-repeat;
                background-size: cover;
                box-shadow: 1px 1px 25px #999;
                color: #fff;
            }
            .jumbotron-main-page h1{
                text-shadow: 1px 3px #333;
            }
            .jumbotron-main-page p{
                text-shadow: 1px 3px #333;
            }
            .icon-message{
                width: 256px !important;
                height: 256px !important;
                position: absolute;
                top: 20%;
                margin-top: 60px;

            }
            .topbar-thumbnail{
                width: 36px;
                height: auto;
                margin-top: -7px;
            }
            .text-main-page{
                margin: 20px;
                font-size: 1.2em;
                text-align: justify;
            }
            .active-tab{
                border-bottom: #93c840 5px solid;
            }
            .second-tier{
                box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #333;
                background-color: #ededed;
            }
            .jumbotron-no-support{
                background-color: #fff;
                border: 5px #999 solid;
            }
            .no-support-panel-text{
                text-align: justify;
                font-size: 1.2em;
            }
            .img-tech-main{
                display: block;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
            }
            .btn-no-support{
                display: block;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                margin-top: 15px;
                width: 200px;
                content: '';
            }
            .frowny-face{
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 130px;
                color: #919191;
                line-height: 1.1;
                margin-top: 0px;
                margin-bottom: 50px;
            }
            .img-tech-main{
                    width: 960px !important;
                    height: auto !important;
            }
            .web-explorer-thumbnail{
                display: block;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                margin-top: 10px;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
            }
            .img-logo-main-page{
                    width: 250px;
                    height: 250px;
                    margin-top: -20px;
                    display: block;
                    margin-left: auto;
                    margin-right: auto;
            }
            .footer{
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 70px;
            }

            @media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px){
                .img-logo-main-page{
                    display: none;
                }
                .img-tech-main{
                    display: none;
                }
                .icon-message{
                    display: none;
                }
            }
            @media only screen and (min-width : 1224px) {
                .jumbotron-main-page{
                    height: 450px;
                    min-height: 300px;
                    max-height: 450px;
                }
                .space-top-jumbotron-main-page{
                    margin-top: 50px;
                }
            }
            @media only screen  and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
                .img-tech-main{
                    display: none;
                }
                .img-logo-main-page{
                    display: none;
                }
                .icon-message{
                    display: none;
                }
            }
```

Here is a picture of what it looks like:

[image: Picture of the white frame that appears on the right side of the page]

If somebody has any idea why this frame appears there please let me know how to fix it!

Comment: That's a god-awful amount of CSS that would be much easier to read if you just posted a link - but my guess is that for one of your elements you are using `padding` or `margin` in addition to `width: 100%` which adds extra space creating this effect.  Just go to inspector and see where the problem lies - right click and inspect element in chrome.

Comment: Do you get the same effect in a different browser(ie firefox)?

Comment: get the same effect on firefox and ie. The only difference is that IE's white frame is a lot smaller than the others. But there's still a small frame.

Answer (score 0):

The browser automatically adds margin to body so you need to remove that by setting the margin to 0.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

This will remove the vertical scrollbar.

In order to find what is causing the blank area to the right you can use the browsers builtin tools. I Firefox you can right click on the page and select "Inspect element" to get info about it and select difference element to se where the elements start to change size.

If you want me to find it, it would be better with a link to the page. I tried your code but i'm not getting the same results as the screenshot.

Answer (score -2):

Have you included CSS reset?

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

(I don't see the white frame in the screenshot)

Comment: See there's like a margin on the right side, that's the white frame I mean, it shouldn't be there.

Comment: Unless you can point to the part of the reset that will fix the problem, this is not an answer.